# Serverless for ecs

Tags: command-line, amazon-ecs, serverless

Is there a cli, like the serverless framework is for lambda, that requires a simple addition to a node or php application that can deploy the code onto an ecs task?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are at least two official methods for deploying ECS tasks easily from the CLI:

You can use [the ecs-cli compose command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html) to deploy to ECS similar to how you would use `docker-compose`.

You can use the new [AWS Copilot CLI tool](https://aws.amazon.com/containers/copilot/).

Comment: Any idea where to find training videos that show how to use it like the question I asked?